# invalid gem format

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, merb

Installing Merb on Ruby Enterprise Edition (OS X) throws this error, any ideas?

```
sudo gem install merb

ERROR:  Error installing merb:
invalid gem format for /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090113/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/ParseTree-3.0.2.gem
```

Deleted the gem cache but the problem persisted. It seemed to manage to install some of the gems though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the cache (ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090113/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/*) and gem folder in question seems to work temporarily although now I have this issue with another dependency merb-action-args..

Comment: Seems to have sorted itself out, a rubygems problem

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the problem was that the URL for the gems was being blocked by our company's web content filter (Websense). I opened the gem file on a text editor and found a blockpage message instead of the actual content, so I had to have the URL unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it. Basically whenever a new gem is installed/updated the system download the from github and then installed it. And we know that work remain always in progress on github for gems. So anyhow gem with incorrect format gets updated.

SO my solution is to download the gem from any of your server/system where the rails application is running and then install it.